# this make graph function is not working. Any ideas?

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, stock

Use the make_graph function to graph the Tesla Stock Data, also provide a title for the graph. The structure to call the make_graph function is make_graph(tesla_data, tesla_revenue, 'Tesla'). Note the graph will only show data upto June 2021.

Any ideas as to how to answer this question? I have been provided with a function below which goes way over my head. I have copied and pasted it as shown.

```py
def make_graph(stock_data, revenue_data, stock):
    fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, subplot_titles=("Historical Share Price", "Historical Revenue"), vertical_spacing = .3)
    stock_data_specific = stock_data[stock_data.Date <= '2021--06-14']
    revenue_data_specific = revenue_data[revenue_data.Date <= '2021-04-30']
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=pd.to_datetime(stock_data_specific.Date, infer_datetime_format=True), y=stock_data_specific.Close.astype("float"), name="Share Price"), row=1, col=1)
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=pd.to_datetime(revenue_data_specific.Date, infer_datetime_format=True), y=revenue_data_specific.Revenue.astype("float"), name="Revenue"), row=2, col=1)
    fig.update_xaxes(title_text="Date", row=1, col=1)
    fig.update_xaxes(title_text="Date", row=2, col=1)
    fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Price ($US)", row=1, col=1)
    fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Revenue ($US Millions)", row=2, col=1)
    fig.update_layout(showlegend=False,
    height=900,
    title=stock,
    xaxis_rangeslider_visible=True)
    fig.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can write this code, then I'm not sure what your question is. If you didn't write the code, you should explain the source and purpose of the code. It is also advisable to attach a sample of the data you are using.
I don't know how to get Tesla's revenue data, so I used the closing price of the stock price data and the volume of the stock price data as revenue data.
Fixed: Added a function call and changed the name of the graph to volume.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

stock_data = yf.download("TSLA", start="2020-01-01", end="2021-09-30", progress=False)
revenue_data = yf.download("TSLA", start="2020-01-01", end="2021-09-30", progress=False)
stock_data.reset_index(inplace=True)
revenue_data.reset_index(inplace=True)

def make_graph(stock_data, revenue_data, stock):
    fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, 
                        shared_xaxes=True, 
                        subplot_titles=("Historical Share Price", "Historical Revenue"), 
                        vertical_spacing=.3)
    
    stock_data_specific = stock_data[stock_data.Date <= '2021-06-14']
    revenue_data_specific = revenue_data[revenue_data.Date <= '2021-04-30']
    
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
        x=pd.to_datetime(stock_data_specific.Date, infer_datetime_format=True),
        y=stock_data_specific.Close.astype("float"), name="Share Price"), row=1, col=1)
    
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=pd.to_datetime(revenue_data_specific.Date, infer_datetime_format=True), 
                             y=revenue_data_specific.Volume.astype("float"),
                             name="Volume"), row=2, col=1)
    
    fig.update_xaxes(title_text="Date", row=1, col=1)
    fig.update_xaxes(title_text="Date", row=2, col=1)
    fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Price ($US)", row=1, col=1)
    fig.update_yaxes(title_text="Revenue ($US Millions)", row=2, col=1)
    
    fig.update_layout(showlegend=False,
                      height=900,
                      title=stock,
                      xaxis_rangeslider_visible=True)
    
    fig.show()
    
make_graph(stock_data, revenue_data, 'TSLA')
```

[image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful to you, there is a check mark under the up and down buttons in the evaluation, please click on the check mark to accept the answer.